# Problem with solving Exception instance of another Exception Error

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception, illegalargumentexception, instanceof

i couldn't solve this error message while testing my programm. Futhermore i didn't even understand the meaning of this error. From my knowledge both exceptions comes from RuntimeException, so why is it assumed that ArrayIndex is an instance of IllegalArgument?

IllegalArgumentException -> RuntimeException
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -> IndexOutOfBoundsException -> RuntimeException

Expecting: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0"
to be exactly an instance of:
 "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
but was:
 "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0"

Comment: Two classes that extend the same parent class are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Can you please add your test code so that the community can help?